# Ways to encrypt a whole directory instead of just a file

Tags: encryption

I want to use GPG for local encryption only, and after reading the man file, I'm doing the following in order to encrypt a whole directory:

I zip the directory with a password "zip -r -e foo foo", then I encrypt it with "gpg -c foo.zip" using a passphrase. Is this an elegant and secure way of encrypting directories? Am I using GPG's full cryptographic power? Are there better alternatives?

So there's no a way to encrypt a whole directory without zip it or tar it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this an elegant and secure way of encrypting directories?

Elegant -- no.  Secure -- as secure as `gpg`.

> Am I using GPG's full cryptographic power?

Yes.

> Are there better alternatives?

`tar` the directory first instead of `zip`.  `gpg` compresses data anyway.